# Error using Amazon SES in grails

Tags: grails, amazon-ses

I've done this tutorial (http://springandgrailsmusings.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/using-amazon-ses-from-grails.html) to integrate amazon sdk plugin for SES in grails, but I have the next error when I try to acces to the view save: |

```
Error 2015-05-26 12:36:53,390 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [GET] /Plugin/sendEmail/save
No signature of method: org.plugin.SendEmailController.sesMail() is applicable for argument types: (org.plugin.SendEmailController$_save_closure2) values: [org.plugin.SendEmailController$_save_closure2@12b5535]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: org.plugin.SendEmailController.sesMail() is applicable for argument types: (org.plugin.SendEmailController$_save_closure2) values: [org.plugin.SendEmailController$_save_closure2@12b5535]
    Line | Method
->>   25 | save      in org.plugin.SendEmailController
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

This is my controller:

```
class SendEmailController {
    static scaffold = true  

   def index() { }

    def save(){
        def mailId = sesMail {
            from "myemail"
            to "youremail"
            subject "test plain text mail"
            body "this is the e-mail content, sent at: (${new Date().format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')})"
        }
        flash.message =  "E-mail sent: ${mailId}"
    }
}
```

My Config.groovy

```
grails {
    plugin {
        aws {
            credentials {
                accessKey = "bbb"
                secretKey = "aaaa"
             }
            ses {
                enabled = true
                from = "mymail"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
        build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2'
        build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2'
        runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2'
        runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2'
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"


        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
        runtime ':aws-sdk:1.9.37'

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your BuildConfig.groovy information? It would be helpful to see which plugins you are using.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I just add the buildConfig.groovy, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have installed the wrong plugin. You need this [aws](https://grails.org/plugin/aws) installed not [the one](https://grails.org/plugins/search?q=aws-sdk) I see in your Buildconfig

Answer (score 0):

Note that you do not need AWS plugin at all since SES accepts standard SMTP protocol.

You can simply use mail plugin.